# Iteration of quotient per ID excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, modulo

I need to assign the quotient of total IDs per ID. And whenever there is a remainder, it will be added into the first cell. I used =COUNTA(B3:B500)/(no. of ids) to get the quotient

The quotient would be divided equally per IDs. Say I have 130 total items, and 4 IDs. I will divide 130 by 4. Answer will be 32.5. So per ID I will have 33, 33, 32, 32. How can I have that iteration where I can have equal counts per ID? and the remainder will be added on the top items. Column B would be Names that needed groupings which is the IDs.

How can I iterate the quotient per ID? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `iterate the quotient per ID`? What would be your expected result?

Comment: The quotient would be divided equally per IDs. Say I have 130 total items, and 4 IDs. I will divide 130 by 4. Answer will be 32.5. So per ID I will have 33, 33, 32, 32. How can I have that iteration where I can have equal counts per ID? and the remainder will be added on the top items @Harun24HR

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you pls illustrate/describe exactly where these items are added ("top items"?)? and what is in range B3:B500 (is it relevant to the question?) and over which range does the remainder need to be added (b3:b500, or the unreferenced cells you've included in screenshot)?

Comment: I updated the question, kindly check @JB-007 thank you

Comment: ahhh - only see this now - too bad but most importantly, looks like accepted answer below serves cause.  (Q looks better too btw :) upvoting accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=CEILING.MATH((A1-SEQUENCE(A2,,0))/A2)
```

[image: rollover]

The excess `ID`'s are absorbed by the `SEQUENCE`, which produces a column array.